# How to configure Cepheus CEP so it returns json to orion instead of xml?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Recently I started using Cepheus CEP but following the documentation I can't make it insert in orion entities. Looking what I made wrong with the accumulator.py I found out that cepheus cep sends xml querys to orion. Isn't xml deprecated in orion?

The configuration used in cepheus cep:

```
{
  "host":"http://localhost:1028",
  "in":[
    {
      "id":"Room.*",
      "type":"Room",
      "isPattern":true,
      "providers":[
        "http://localhost:1027"
      ],
      "attributes":[
        { "name":"temperature", "type":"double" },
        { "name":"floor", "type":"string" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "out":[
    {
      "id":"Floor1",
      "type":"Floor",
      "brokers":[
        {
          "url":"http://localhost:1029"
        }
      ],
      "attributes":[
        { "name":"temperature", "type":"double" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statements":[
    "INSERT INTO Floor SELECT floor as id, avg(temperature) as temperature FROM Room.win:time(10 min) GROUP BY floor OUTPUT LAST EVERY 10 sec"
  ]
}
```

- 1029 Orion Broker
- 1028 Cepheus CEP
- 1027 Cepheus Broker

The response I'm getting with accumulator.py:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2016 05:50:46] "POST /ngsi10/updateContext HTTP/1.1" 200 -
POST http://localhost:1029/ngsi10/updateContext
Content-Length: 404
User-Agent: Apache-HttpAsyncClient/4.1 (Java/1.8.0_91)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost:1029
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml

<updateContextRequest><updateAction>APPEND</updateAction><contextElementList><contextElement><entityId type="Floor" isPattern="false"><id>Floor1</id></entityId><contextAttributeList><contextAttribute><name>temperature</name><type>double</type><contextValue>22.333333333333332</contextValue><metadata/></contextAttribute></contextAttributeList></contextElement></contextElementList></updateContextRequest>=======================================
```

And if in Cepheus Broker if I enabled

```
remote.forward.updateContext = true
```

with the correct broker config I get the following error:

```
2016-05-13 06:07:08.504  WARN 12977 --- [nio-1027-exec-8] c.o.c.broker.controller.NgsiController   : UpdateContext failed for http://localhost:1026: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

I think this error is also produced because the xml format of the querys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cepheus 0.1.16 is not compatible with Orion after 0.28 as XML support was removed. I added an issue to Cepheus to track this problem: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus/issues/51

[Update] [Cepheus 0.1.17](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus/releases/tag/0.1.7) was released with JSON as the default format for NGSI exchanges.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea of the release date?